# Add version # to wp_register_style function

Tags: functions, cache

How do I add a version number correctly?

I have checked [wordpress codex but their wp register style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_style/) function looks different than mine and I don't want to break anything.

Here is mine

```
wp_register_style( 'customStyles', plugins_url( 'css/custom-styles.css', __FILE__ ) );
```

Here is WordPress codexs'

```
wp_register_style( string $handle, string|bool $src, string[] $deps = array(), string|bool|null $ver = false, string $media = 'all' )
```

Is this correct?

```
wp_register_style( 'customStyles', plugins_url( 'css/custom-styles.css', FILE ) $ver = 301 );
```

Comment: Just add the required argument. Is there something specific you don't understand?

Comment: wp_register_style( 'customStyles', plugins_url( 'css/custom-styles.css', __FILE__ ) $ver =301 );   yeah I don't understand how to properly add the version number.

Comment: Not to be rude but this is a very basic PHP question. I suggest reviewing some introductory PHP information if you plan on making code changes to your site. You just need: `wp_register_style( 'customStyles', plugins_url( 'css/custom-styles.css', __FILE__ ), array(), 301 );`

Comment: Yes, I know I like taking everything in and then going from there. Even simple PHP questions. Thank you for taking the time to read and commment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is how to read the documentation. The bold code at the top shows how the function is *declared by WordPress,* not how to use it.

Let's break it down:

```
wp_register_style( 
    string $handle, 
    string|bool $src, 
    string[] $deps = array(), 
    string|bool|null $ver = false, 
    string $media = 'all' 
)
```

Every possible variable has it's type in front. If more than one type is accepted, they are listed with a `|` between them. `string[]` means an array of strings. You do not have to use the parameter names when you use the function.

So if you want to use such a function, you can just pass the required values in the same order as in the declaration, and with the same type of course:

```
wp_register_style( 
    'darkmode', 
    get_template_directory_uri() '/darkmode.css', 
    [], 
    '3.2' // the version! 
);
```

Parameters with default values, like here `$media = 'all'`, can be omitted completely.

Comment: Really appreciate you taking the time to explain that. Thank you